# jquery validate & form submit conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with numerous fields. When the user submits it, I need to validate fields first, so I am using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#MainForm").validate({});
});
```

However, I also have other code - some action code to run when the submit was correct.  But it always prevents the first script from finishing and doesn't allow me to validate the form.

```
$("#MainForm").submit(function(){
    $(".modal-after-submit").show();    
});
```

What can I do to make the second code run just after validation was successfully passed?

Comment: You need to call `validate()` before form submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to follow this pattern:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    // do other things for a valid form
    form.submit();
  }
});
```

In your case, it could be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#MainForm").validate({
      submitHandler: function(form) {
         $(".modal-after-submit").show();  
         // do something else
         form.submit();
      }
   });
});
```

For reference:[jQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#-validate())

Answer (score 0):

in jquery validation you can combine both function in one, please follow as below

```
$("#MainForm").validate({
      submitHandler: function (event) {
          $(".modal-after-submit").show();
        }
       });
```